# The size for values of type `T` cannot be known at compilation time when using mem::size_of::<T> as an array length

Tags: generics, rust

Consider the following function:

```
fn make_array<T>()
where
    T: Sized,
{
    let bytes = [0u8; std::mem::size_of::<T>()];
}
```

For whatever reason it fails to compile

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `T` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:5:23
  |
5 |     let bytes = [0u8; std::mem::size_of::<T>()];
  |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `T`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
  = help: consider adding a `where T: std::marker::Sized` bound
  = note: required by `std::mem::size_of`
```

This is despite the fact that there is a `Sized` trait bound for the generic parameter `T`. It doesn't make any sense to me.

Why is this happening and how do I work around it?

Comment: [Compile-time generic type size check](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30330519/155423); [How to use associated constants to define the length of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51131229/155423); [What expressions are allowed as the array length N in \[_; N\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49468122/155423)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be bug #43408: [Array lengths don't support generic parameters](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43408).