# constant expression depends on a generic parameter this may fail depending on what value the parameter takes

Tags: rust, unsafe

I want to use `std::mem::transmute` and `std::mem::size_of` using a generic parameter.

But Rust gives me the following error:

```
constant expression depends on a generic parameter this may fail depending on what value the parameter takes
```

here is a simplified version that should create a zeroed struct of type T and return it:

```rust
fn test<T>() -> T {
    let buf = [0u8; std::mem::size_of::<T>()];
    unsafe { std::mem::transmute(buf) }
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Do I have to add some kind of type constraint to T?

Note that this is just a simplified version of what I want to do, to create a zeroed struct you can use `std::mem::zeroed()` as @PitaJ noted

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/61956

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The size for values of type \`T\` cannot be known at compilation time when using mem::size\_of::<T> as an array length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56705334/the-size-for-values-of-type-t-cannot-be-known-at-compilation-time-when-using-m)

Comment: so there is no way to create a generic version of this? except for maybe writing a macro?

Comment: There are no known workarounds at the moment without enabling nightly unstable features: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43408

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::mem::zeroed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.zeroed.html) instead:

```rust
fn test<T>() -> T {
    // Only sound if zeroed is a valid representation of T
    unsafe { std::mem:zeroed() }
}
```

Comment: yes I know, this is just a simplified example for reproducing the error :)